# Python ctypes, working with struct typedefs

Tags: python, ctypes

Say I have the following c code:

```
typedef struct _test test;

struct _test {
    test*    just_a_test;
    char*    just_a_char;
};
```

Would the following implementation work?

```
class test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('just_a_test', POINTER(test)),
        ('just_a_char', c_char_p),
    ]
```

I'm just confused regarding the first pointer in the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will not work because at the time it references `test`, the class hasn't been created yet.

This exact problem in described in `ctypes` documentation under [15.17.1.16. Incomplete Types](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types).

The solution is to set `_fields_` *after* creating the class:

```
class test(Structure):
    pass
test._fields_ = [
    ('just_a_test', POINTER(test)),
    ('just_a_char', c_char_p),
]
```